Double click on cell filters the column for cell value or text in same column
i want a vba code to filter for cell value when double click on it if it is value or text ( cell contents )
the filter applies on only column range (C3:C)  ( containing the cell which i double clicked )
steps like these IMAGES
enter image description here before filter
enter image description here after filter
thnx in advance
i tried a code filters in another sheet but could not use in same sheet
i found this but the double click event works on all sheet i want to specify a cloumn ex:(C3:C) to run the event
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.EnableEvents = False
cancel = True
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
 MsgBox "No valid filter value selected"
 GoTo GetOut
End If

   Sheet1.Range("c2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="" & ActiveCell.Value
   Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("A1")

GetOut:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End Sub


Help things out by first recording a macro for a filter by selection sequence and then posting the code for it.

i am here to get help i am not expert i search for codes and edit so i can use in my sheets for work only  i tried code that filters by double click on another sheet but did not work .

Using the macro recorder is a basic level of effort for helping the people who want to help you. Please review this link. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

I saw you were using a table so...
Put this code in your sheet code and run the CreateHyperlinks first use the hyperlink follow event instead of the doubleclick, change the necessary things as needed. Also mark my response as the answer if it helped you! Good Luck!
Private Property Get YourSheet() As Worksheet
    'Change this to your sheet name
    Set YourSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property

Private Property Get YourTable() As ListObject
    ' Change this to your table name
    Set YourTable = YourSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
End Property

Private Property Get YourField() As ListColumn
    Set YourField = YourTable.ListColumns("JRNL")
End Property

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    YourTable.Range.AutoFilter Target.Range.Column, Target.Range.Value
End Sub



Public Sub CreateHyperlinks()
    ' Run this script first to write out the hyperlinks
    
    Dim vrngEach As Range
    For Each vrngEach In YourField.DataBodyRange

        vrngEach.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=vrngEach, Address:="", SubAddress:=YourSheet.Name & "!" & vrngEach.Address(False, False), TextToDisplay:=vrngEach.Value
    Next vrngEach
    
End Sub


hello sir ,first thnx for help , i edited the code to my data but  got error massage "subscript out of range"
